# send images from Arduino Uno to raspberry pi

Tags: arduino-uno

I am a new to work with ov7670 camera module and Arduino . please let me know whether it could be possible to send images captured from ov7670 module with Arduino Uno to Raspberry pi??

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to connect the OV7670 directly to the Raspberry Pi?

Comment: It really would be way easier to directly use the Pi's camera interface and ditching the Uno. The Uno is not good for handling images, though it is generally capable of doing it (in limits). If you want to go on vacation you wouldn't try to tow your car with a boby car to the destination. You would directly use the car itself, because it is way more capable.

Comment: Thanks for your response :) .But would it be possible to connect ov7670 to raspberry pi directly?? In some websites I saw that 0V7670 is a arducam and doesn't compatible with raspberry pi ?? Isn't it ? Pls let me know ASAP .